# Geographical Coordinates on R Studio

Tags: r, google-maps

I am developing a new software related to sea turtles, and as I am new using R, I would like to ask for some help.

In one step of the software, the user has to indicate the coordinates of where it is working (a beach in Brazil, Florida, etc.).

Based on this coordinates, I'd like R Studio to show a map of the country/region and mark with a circle or a X the exact point of the given coordinates.

Is there any package that allows me to do it easily?

Comment: See the package ggmap, [available at CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggmap/index.html)

Comment: @Andrie Although short I think that probably qualifies as an answer. It's exactly what he was looking for.

Comment: @Swires I know, but I don't have the time to write a proper answer.  Please go ahead :-)